# Show that there exists $x \in \mathbb R$ such that $\mathbb P (Y = x ) = 1.$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

> Let $\{x_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of real numbers and $\{X_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of random variables such that $\mathbb P (X_n = x_n) = 1,\ n \geq 1.$ Let $Y$ be a random variable such that $X_n \stackrel{d} \to Y.$ Then there exists $x \in \mathbb R$ such that $\mathbb P (Y = x) = 1.$

**My Attempt** $:$ Let $y$ be a continuity point of $F_Y.$ Then $F_{X_n} (y) \xrightarrow {n \to \infty} F_{Y} (y).$ Since $F_{X_n} (z) \in \{0,1\}$ it follows that $F_Y (z) \in \{0,1\}.$ But since $F_Y (z) \to 1$ as $z \to \infty$ and $F_Y (z) \to 0$ as $z \to -\infty$ it follows that $F_Y (z) = 1$ for sufficiently large $z$ and $F_Y (z) = 0$ for sufficiently small $z$ and hence the set $A : = \{z \in \mathbb R\ |\ F_Y (z) = 1 \}$ is non-empty and bounded below. Let $x : = \inf A.$ Then $F_Y (z) = 0$ for all $z \lt x.$ Choose a sequence $\{y_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ in $A$ such that $y_n \downarrow x$ as $n \to \infty.$ Then for any $z \gt x$ there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $y_n \lt z$ for all $n \geq N.$ Since $F_Y$ is monotone increasing it follows that $F_Y (z) \geq F_Y (y_{N}) = 1$ i.e. $F_Y (z) = 1$ for all $z \gt x.$ But since $F_Y$ is right-continuous it then follows that $F_Y (x) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} F_Y (y_n) = 1.$ So $$F_Y (z) = \begin{cases} 1 & z \geq x \\ 0 & z \lt x \end{cases}$$ Finally we observe that $\left [x - \frac {1} {n} \lt Y \leq x \right ] \big\downarrow\ [Y = x]$ and hence by the continuity of the probability measure from above it follows that $$\begin{align*} \mathbb P(Y = x) & = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \mathbb P \left (x - \frac {1} {n} \lt Y \leq x \right ) \\ & = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left ( F_Y (x) - F_Y \left (x - \frac {1} {n} \right ) \right ) \\ & = 1. \end{align*}$$

Is it fine what I did? Thanks for reading.

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

The following general statement holds: let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of elements of $\mathbb{R}^d$; if $(f(x_n))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges for any continuous and bounded $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$, then $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges (*). Therefore, if $P(X_n=x_n)=1$ then $E[f(X_n)]=f(x_n)$ and so you just need to assert that $(E[f(X_n)])_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent for any continuous and bounded $f$ to have $x_n\to x$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$. It then follows that $E[e^{i\xi\cdot  X_n}]=e^{i\xi\cdot  x_n}\to e^{i\xi \cdot x}$ for any $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and the latter characterises the law of $Y$ s.t. $P(Y=x)=1$.

---

(*) This is a special case of Exercise 8.10.67 in [Bogachev, Vol II](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-34514-5).